# Create a new array from values in a loop, then sum all values from new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, sum

I have a form with multiple rows where a user can input numbers and calculate outputs.

I can currently calculate the output of each row - the sub-total. But would like to be able to calculate all sub-totals - the total.

I'm able to log each sub-total to the console, but cannot figure out how to sum those values. Having read some similar questions I reckon I need to create an array of the values and sum those values.

Is this possible using the loop I'm currently using?

Here's what I currently have:

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
const calculate = document.querySelector('.calculate');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

// Calculate

function calculateSubTotal() {

  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    const input1Val = Number(row.querySelector('.input-1').value);
    const input2Val = Number(row.querySelector('.input-2').value);

    const subTotal = input1Val + input2Val;

    console.log(subTotal);
  });

}

calculate.addEventListener('click', calculateSubTotal);
```

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/WBXjWO?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable outside `forEach` and increase it inside `forEach`

```
function calculateSubTotal() {
  let total = 0;
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    const input1Val = Number(row.querySelector('.input-1').value);
    const input2Val = Number(row.querySelector('.input-2').value);

    const subTotal = input1Val + input2Val;

    console.log(subTotal);
    total += subTotal 
  });

}
```

A simplified version of your code using `reduce()` and `map()` will be

```
function calculateSubTotal() {
  let total = 0;
  let subTotals = rows.map(x => +x.querySelector('.input-1').value + +x.querySelector('.input-2').value)
  let total = subTotals.reduce((ac,a) => ac + a,0)
}
```